# Expo DevTools shows An Unexpected Error Occured

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

So, before anyone asks for the minimal code, I haven't wrote one yet. It's the default template. I just set up the environment and made a new project and ran `npm start` to test it out. However, DevTools opens up in my browser at localhost:19002 but with this error: "An Unexpected Error has occured." It's a completely black screen with only this error text. However, I can still scan the QR code using my iPhone. There are no error logs in the terminal except: `` npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead. `` but I doubt they are linked. Are they though?

Comment: Did you try to update to the latest version of expo cli? https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/866

Comment: @pwrngr I want on the latest version and had the same issue so rolled 1 version back but it didn't seem to fix it too. I'll try the latest version again now.

Comment: Same error again. @pwrngr

Comment: If you check the browser's console, it says `process is not defined`
Looks like a bug to me in the latest cli

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution! Apparently expo-cli v5.4.10 has some issues with the web interface. Rolled back to 5.4.9 and DevTools work again now.
This is the rollback command `npm i -g expo-cli@5.4.9`

Answer (score 2):

Expo has been intending on removing the web interface for a while now (in v6.0.0), as shown in this article: https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206. Instead, you will have to use the command line to test your app. I personally don't see how it is easier, but it is not a bug, the expo team have intentionally deprecated the web interface.

I suggest that you try to learn the command line interface, because as soon as you need to update expo cli, then you will have no choice.